# How do I add a custom message to a required property with a min and max size using fluent api?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement `fluent API` instead of `DataAnnotations`
and i have 2 problems

1. I don't know how to add a custom message for the `required` property
2. I don't know how to specify a minimum size and a maximum size

Example of what I want to do.

I am trying to convert this:

```cs
    public class Inventory
    {
        [Key]
        public int inventory_id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es obligatorio"), StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "{0} la longitud debe estar entre {2} y {1}.", MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
    }
```

Using fluent API

```cs
namespace API.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Requirement> Requirements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Inventory> Iventories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region Inventory
            // iventory ID
            modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
                .HasKey(i => i.inventory_id);
            // Name
            modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .Property(i => i.name)
            .IsRequired(true, ErrorMessage("is Requerid!"));
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RequiredAttribute` is part of the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace which is used by a lot of microsoft and others external libraries in different ways based on the destination scope.

E.g.: the `ErrorMessage` property is used by asp .net MVC to add an error to the ModelState, but in EF Core the same property is simply ignored because it is not applicable to the context (where should ef core put this error message in a database?).

In the end, you still have to put the RequiredAttribute to the model in order to show the error message but at the same time you can use the Required() method in Ef core to set a not null column in the db table.

Comment: I think I got it, so you're telling me to combine the `required()` method and the `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: Yes because they serve to two different purpose you can't express just with only one the two. so you need both.